# Запятая перед определяемым словом

Tags: пунктуация, определения

Снова предложение из книги: "Еще одна чрезвычайно влиятельная, философски ориентированная, школа этого направления - сарвастивада, базовым тезисом которой...".

Почему перед определяемым словом *школа* стоит запятая? Ведь определение не отделено от опред. слова другими словами. Также оно не относиться и к лич. местоимению. Объясните постановку, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пояснительные члены предложения выделяются с обеих сторон. Если в тексте нет ошибки, то только второе определение (*философски ориентированная*) является уточнением. Это выглядит странно, но не зная предмета, трудно судить. Другие возможности: считать, что здесь нет поясняющих членов, или считать оба опредления вместе (*чрезвычайно влиятельная, философски ориентированная*) поясняющим членом.

Возможные варианты:

Еще одна чрезвычайно влиятельная, философски ориентированная школа этого направления — сарвастивада, базовым тезисом которой...

Еще одна — чрезвычайно влиятельная, философски ориентированная — школа этого направления — сарвастивада, базовым тезисом которой...

Еще одна, чрезвычайно влиятельная, философски ориентированная, школа этого направления — сарвастивада, базовым тезисом которой...

Comment: [Предложение полностью](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiBEK.jpg)  Опечатка, наверное.

Comment: Если в тексте нет ошибки, то только второе определение (*философски ориентированная*) является уточнением. Я поправил мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Еще одна чрезвычайно влиятельная, философски ориентированная школа этого направления - сарвастивада, базовым тезисом которой...

Я бы не стала ставить запятую, это два однородных определения перед определяемым словом.

Если поставить запятую, то второе определение должно считаться уточняющим, но это вряд ли соответствует содержанию текста.